# Proof that the number of edges is a Graph is at least twice the number of edges surrounding all the sides of the Graph

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a planar Graph with $n$ vertices.
Let $F$ be the set of all the the faces of $G$. Is is given that the length of the biggest Graph face is $c$.
Let $A$ be the set of all the pairs, $A = \{(e,f)|E * F \ni (e,f), \text{where }e\text{ is surrounding }F\}$
Prove that:
$|A|\le 2|E|$
and that:
$|A|\ge c|F|$

Who should I solve this problem? I tried induction but I don't seem to figure out the proof of the base case/what the best case even is. And I couldn't solve the question using any of the theorem regarding planar Graphs.

What is the method of solution is this case?

Comment: What's a vertical graph ? what is the side of a graph ? those are non-standard definitions (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_graph_theory_terms)

Comment: @PaulHudford vertical means its draw-able so that no two arcs overlap eachother, and a side of a Graph is an inner circle of the graphs or the outer circle of a graph

Comment: So by vertical you mean planar, and by side you mean a face of a planar graph? And what is the length of a side; do you mean the number of edges around a face?

Comment: @JaapScherphuis exactly. The question is translated so I may have mistranslated some words.

Comment: Are you sure it's not $|A|=2|E|$ and $|A|\le c|F|$?

Comment: @JaapScherphuis I have checked again. Its the way I have asked originally

Comment: Every edge borders exactly two faces, so $A$ contains exactly two pairs for each edge. Or are you excluding the outside face because its edges don't "surround" it?

Comment: @JaapScherphuis It doesn't have to be like exactly 2, because side can be bordered with more or exactly two arcs

Comment: What do you mean by arc? Please look up the standard English terms and try to use those. Also, edit your question so that it uses those terms, otherwise no one will answer it.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis It is from the Glossary. "Also called edge" And I will change my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this example planar graph:

[image]

It has three faces; A has 4 edges, B has 3 edges, and C has 5 edges.

For each face I've put a grey dot next to each edge bordering the face. These dots represent the elements of the set $$A=\{(e,f)\in E\times F | \text{ edge }e\text{ is next to face }f \}$$. Clearly in this example there are $4+3+5=12$ of them. In general
$$|A|=\sum_{f\in F}d(f)$$
where $d(f)$ is the number of edges around face $f$.

If we put $c=\max_{f\in F} d(f)$ so $d(f)\le c$ for every $f$, then we get $$|A|=\sum_{f\in F}d(f)<\sum_{f\in F}c=c|F|$$. This inequality is in the opposite direction to the one in the question. In the example graph we have $c=5$, $|F|=3$, and so $|A|=4+3+5<5+5+5=3\cdot5=15$. This is therefore clearly a counterexample to the statement.

These dots can also be counted another way. Every edge has exactly two dots next to it, one on either side. In the example case there are $6$ edges, leading to $2\cdot6=12$ dots. In general $|A|=2|E|$, which is an equality rather than the inequality in the question.

So either the statement given in the OP is wrong, or the set $A$ in the statement is somehow different to the set $A$ as I've defined it.

Comment: But not all edges need to border  two dots, they can border one. consider the graph v1--v2--v3--v4

Comment: @avivgood2 You are right that I overlooked the case of graphs with vertices of degree 1. That would explain why $|A|\le2|E|$ instead of equality. Nevertheless, the inequality involving $c|F|$ goes the other way for my example graph (and for all planar graphs without degree 1 vertices). And if you do allow degree 1 vertices, then it is not clear how you define faces exactly, and what value $c$ get. So I still think the problem statement is wrong or incomplete in some way.